# Derivative Of Product Confusion

Tags: calculus

$$\frac{d}{dx} f(x)g(x) =g(x)\frac{d}{dx}f(x)+f(x)\frac{d}{dx}g(x)$$

I think it should be $$\frac{d}{dx} f(x)g(x)= f(x)\frac{d}{dx}g(x) \times \frac{d}{dx}f(x)$$

Can somebody elaborate on it?

Comment: If that was true, we wouldn't have $\frac d{dx}f(x)g(x)=\frac d{dx}g(x)f(x)$.

Comment: Remember that:$$\frac d{dx}y(x)=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{y(x+h)-y(x)}h$$Here you have $y(x)=f(x)g(x)$.

Comment: You should really get in the habit of putting parentheses around terms. Otherwise things can be very ambiguous.

Comment: @columbus8myhw Actually every function would have derivative identically $0$, so your equation would still hold :)

Comment: @GPerez Ah, true. (Let $g(x)=1$.)

Comment: What led you to think that was true?

Answer (score 1):

This is called the product rule. And your thinking is incorrect. If you have two functions for example $f(x) = x$ and $g(x) = \sin(x)$ then if you multiply these two functions together $f(x)g(x) = x \sin(x)$ and you want to take the derivative of that product, they you apply the first formula (The product rule).

First you take the derivative of $f(x)$ then you multiply it by $g(x)$ after that you take the derivative of $g(x)$ and you multiply it by $f(x)$ and they you add these two multiples. And so in my example the answer would be as follows

$$\color{blue}{(f(x)g(x))^\prime = x^\prime \sin x + (\sin x)^\prime x = \sin x + x\cos x}$$

Answer (score 1):

You are wrong. You can simply see that for two strigt lines $f(x)=ax$ and $g(x)=bx$ it does not work. (You can see it?)

The first formula is the **product rule** for derivative and there are many proof. You can see:http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_rule#Proofs.